# Prove $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $H = \{A\in GL(n, \mathbb{R} | \text{det}(A) = a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subgroup of GL(n, $\mathbb{R}$).

My plan is to use the Two-Step Subgroup Test in which we show for a nonempty set $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if whenever $a,b \in H$, $ab\in H$ and $a^{-1} \in H$. I don't have a lot of practice with this process, so I am unsure how to go about the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B\in H$.

Then, $\det(A) = p+q\sqrt2$ with $p,q \in \Bbb Q$ and $\det(B) = r+s\sqrt2$ with $r,s \in \Bbb Q$.

Then, $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B) = (pr+2qs)+(ps+qr)\sqrt2 \ne 0$ (why?), so $AB \in H$.

Similarly, $\det(A^{-1}) = \det(A)^{-1} = \dfrac{p}{p^2-2q^2} - \dfrac{q}{p^2-2q^2}\sqrt2 \ne 0$ (why?), so $A^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to homomorphisms, this is easier because $\det: GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is a homomorphism of groups and your $H$ is the inverse image of the subgroup $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]^*$.